# "Missing" вместо картинки после обновления записи Rails 4 и Papercip

Tags: multiset, изображения, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Rails 4 и Paperclip. Суть в том, что модель News имеет много Assets, а Assets в свою очередь has_attached_files :image. При создании новости и первоначальном добавлении изображения все работает ок, но стоит только попытаться обносить новость и появляется надпись рядом с существующими изображениями "Missing". Ломаю голову уже который день. Как видно из дебага, оно каким-то образом создает пустые поля и кладет их в базу. Скринкасты смотрел - не помогло)

```
 - !ruby/object:Asset
  attributes:
    id: 15
    news_id: 6
    created_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:13.911636000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:13.911636000 Z
    image_file_name: i.jpeg
    image_content_type: image/jpeg
    image_file_size: 7588
    image_updated_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:13.590711000 Z
- !ruby/object:Asset
  attributes:
    id: 16
    news_id: 6
    created_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:25.020018000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:25.020018000 Z
    image_file_name: oyq9RdCvuBs.jpg
    image_content_type: image/jpeg
    image_file_size: 58961
    image_updated_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:24.453373000 Z
- !ruby/object:Asset
  attributes:
    id: 17
    news_id: 6
    created_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:25.039454000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-01-22 02:08:25.039454000 Z
    image_file_name: 
    image_content_type: 
    image_file_size: 
    image_updated_at:
```

This is models:

```
 class News < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :assets
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy=>true
 end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at
  belongs_to :news

  has_attached_file :image, 
    :styles => {
      :thumb => '150X150#',
      :medium => '300X300>',
      :large => '600x600'
    }
end
```

Это контроллер для новостей.
    class NewsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @news = News.all
      end

```
  def show
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @news = News.new
    5.times { @news.assets.build }
  end

  def create
    @news = News.new(news_params)
    if @news.save
      redirect_to @news, :notice => "Successfully created News."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
    5.times { @news.assets.build }
  end

  def update
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
    if @news.update_attributes(news_params)
      redirect_to @news, :notice  => "Successfully updated News."
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @news = News.find(params[:id])
    @news.destroy
    redirect_to news_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed News."
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_news
      @news = News.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def news_params
      params.require(:news).permit(:id,:title, :content, assets_attributes: :image)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте модель News добавить это:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes.any? { |key, value| value.blank? } }
```

В модель Asset советую добавить это:

```
validates_attachment_presence :image
```

Правда это для третьих рельс...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @mayar. Пробовал и такой вариант, не получилось. 
Решил вопрос другим путем. К сожалению из-за маленькой репутации не могу отвечать на свои вопросы, поэтому приведу ответ здесь. Обнаружил в логе еще одну ошибку Unpermitted params: id. Для решения необходимо изменить строчку в news_params. Должно получиться следующее:
  def news_params
    params.require(:news).permit(:id,:title, :content, 
                                 assets_attributes:[:id,:image])
  end